# My header row multiples Each time on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[HeaderRowMultiplesEachTimeAjax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7clD.jpg)

I have a web grid table in JavaScript. Whole table is in HTML. Top header which acts like colgroup caption table is built via js insertion as below:

```
var headerRow = "<tr><th colspan='7' style='background-color: transparent'></th><th style='background-color: #636363; border-bottom:3px solid #fff;  font-weight:bold;' colspan='9'>Overall Statistics</th><th style='background-color: #636363; border-bottom:3px solid #fff;  font-weight:bold;' colspan='9'>Office Statistics</th><th style='background-color: #636363; border-bottom:3px solid #fff;  font-weight:bold;' colspan='9'>Nursing Home Statistics</th><th colspan='2' style='background-color: transparent'></th></tr>";
```

Refer Image. In that I have a link. when I click on link(in ClinicalIssue Column) I should get a popup . Am getting. but each time am clicking the column link, the Header row repeats 3 Times on first Click,
                             7 times on second click, 16 times on third and goes on. So is there to any way to stop this repetition. the whole function code is as below

```js
function SetGridHeaderStyles() {
  //Insert a header row above the grid header
  var headerRow = "<tr><th colspan='7' style='background-color: transparent'></th><th style='background-color: #636363; border-bottom:3px solid #fff;  font-weight:bold;' colspan='9'>Overall Statistics</th><th style='background-color: #636363; border-bottom:3px solid #fff;  font-weight:bold;' colspan='9'>Office Statistics</th><th style='background-color: #636363; border-bottom:3px solid #fff;  font-weight:bold;' colspan='9'>Nursing Home Statistics</th><th colspan='2' style='background-color: transparent'></th></tr>";
  var existingHeader = $("#Grid").html();
  $("#Grid thead tr").before(headerRow);
  $('.gridWithExtRw tr:eq(1) th').resizable({
    handles: "e",
    resize: function(event) {
      $('.gridWithExtRw th').parent('tr').find('.ui-resizable-handle').css({
        'height': $(this).height() + 21 + "px"
      });
    }
  });
```

The code for ajax call is as follows :

```js
function LoadClinicalIssuesPopup(page, providerKey, pos) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/sampleproj/PhysicianWebRanking/ClinicalIssues',
    data: {
      'page': page,
      'providerKey': providerKey,
      'pos': pos
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#ClinicalIssuesPopup").empty();
      $("#ClinicalIssuesPopup").html(data);
      $('.blockingDiv').fadeIn(1);
      PeekabooOn(ClinicalIssuesPopup);
      $("#ClinicalIssuesPopup").focus();
    },
    complete: function() {
      ajaxLoading = false;
    },
    cache: false
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following thing (make tr of head empty before insert).

```
 $("#Grid thead tr").empty().before(headerRow);
```

Or

```
$("#Grid thead tr").html(headerRow);
```

Comment: Nope. the above solution didn't work. the row(header) which contains state, zip code disappears(Refer image link on top). But the expected behavior is , the top row (which contains overall stat,office stat) should not repeat. It should appear only one time. Is there any changes I should make in LoadClinicalIssuesPopup() function? Am new learner so struck a lot on this.